# How do I use a CloudFormation function in UserData Script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

How do I get public IP of EC2 instance and write to a text file in UserData. Tried the following, but as expected it wrote the text literally, rather than resolving it.

```
  UserData:
    Fn::Base64: !Sub |
      #!/bin/bash -xe
      echo "Public IP: " !GetAtt Bastion.PublicIp > /home/ec2-user/readme.txt
```

Thanks in advance! (PS : It has to be yaml)

Comment: Did you try: `echo "Public IP: ${Bastion.PublicIp}"`?

Comment: I get then circular reference error as the UserData is of Bastion server itself. And if I don't mention "Bastion", it fails

Comment: You can get the public IPv4 address on-instance using `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4`.

Comment: Yes jarmod, but was really trying to make use of this concept, and publicip was just an example. was trying to build up something on top.

Comment: The userdata is populated before the instance is launched afaik so the public IP is not yet known.

Comment: What other data do you need, apart from public ip?

Answer (score 0):

Considering TC's comment that PublicIP was specified just as an example let me share a piece of code using multi-line Sub function to build user-data script also utilising an ImportValue function:

```
  GhostServerLaunchTemplate:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate'
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateName: GhostServerLaunchTemplate
      LaunchTemplateData:
        IamInstanceProfile:
          Arn: !ImportValue 'Lab-GhostAppInstanceProfile-ARN'
        ImageId: !Ref EC2AMIImageId
        InstanceType: t2.micro
        NetworkInterfaces:
         - AssociatePublicIpAddress: 'True'
           Groups:
            - !ImportValue 'Lab-EC2PoolSG'
        MetadataOptions:
          HttpTokens: optional
        KeyName: !Ref EC2KeyName
        UserData: !Base64 
          "Fn::Sub": 
            - |
              #!/bin/bash -xe
              ### some code is omitted
              sudo -u ghost_user cat << EOF > config.development.json
              {
                "url": "http://${LbDnsName}",
                "server": {
                  "port": 2368,
                  "host": "0.0.0.0"
                }
              }
              EOF
            - LbDnsName:
                !ImportValue 'Lab-LoadBalancer-DNSName'
```